# Cheerio Doesn't work when I upload an html file

Tags: node.js, express, cheerio

I'm using the following function which implements express in nodejs. I'm also using the cheerio library to do some web scraping. The below function works just fine, but that's not exactly what I want. instead of passing the URL like this, I want to upload the file directly.

```
 router.post('/transcript', async (req,res)=>{
  
  
  const result = await request.get("https://www.codingwithstefan.com/table-example/");
  const $ = cheerio.load(result);
  $("body > table > tbody > tr > td").each((index, element) => {
    console.log($(element).text());
  });
  
});
```

I was running into multiple problems with cheerio, and I decided to test it using the URL inside my call. the website is simply a table no more. Now what I want to actually do is the same but instead of passing the URL like this, I want to upload my HTML file Directly. I simply saved the website by right-clicking on the page and save as. I simply saved the HTML file of the webpage on my desktop (It's named b.html). Now I'm implementing the same function but instead of passing the URL like this I simply pass the HTML file as the request using the following curl command `curl -d  "@C:/Users/yehya/Desktop/b.html" http://localhost:5000/api/transcript`. The function is almost exactly the same but instead of the URL the cheerio.load() take in the req.body. Sadly this does not work, and I cannot understand why. the call never returns anything, I also tried playing around with it but either get null or undefined. I cant understand why this exact same thing doesn't work. I'm guessing when I upload HTML files like this something changes but I cannot figure out the problem here. I've been staring at my screen for days, Help would be appreciated thanks.

```
router.post('/transcript', async (req,res)=>{
  
  
  const $ = cheerio.load(req.body);
  $("body > table > tbody > tr > td").each((index, element) => {
    console.log($(element).text());
  });
  
});
```

Comment: How did you try to load the file? `fs.readFileSync`? Did you add an encoding of `utf8` while reading the file?

Comment: var fs = require('fs'); that all i did to load fs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay you are doing a couple wrong things in your code. Here's a list:

1. Your code does not have a middleware for handling file upload. So that means you are not passing the content of the HTML file as expected. An empty string is passed and so, it does not generate the contents of the table cell.
2. Your curl request is wrong. For file upload, you need to use the `-F` flag.

Here's a complete working snippet I tested with your code and the source file:

index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const multer = require('multer');

const uploader = multer();
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', uploader.single('src'), async (req, res, nxt) => {
    const src = req.file;
    const content = src.buffer.toString('utf8');
    const $ = cheerio.load(content);
    $("body > table > tbody > tr > td").each((index, element) => {
        console.log($(element).text());
    });
    //console.log(root);
    res.json({ status: 200 });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App started');
});
```

You need to install `multer` and `body-parser` to get it working (it may work without body parser but it will be needed for handling other POST requests). You can install them like this: `npm i --save multer body-parser`. Read up more on multer and body-parser on their npm/github page.

Secondly, to upload the file, the curl request should be the following:

```sh
curl -X POST -F 'src=@/path/to/src-file.html' http://localhost:3000/
```

Note one thing: the name passed to the `uploader` middleware, `src` is the same name used for uploading the file with `curl`.