# Express file upload yelds "Unexpected end of form" no matter what

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, file-upload

I'm trying to add a simple file upload API endpoint to my [Express+no-stress+Typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-express-no-stress-typescript) app, so I started with what seemed to be the easy way, i.e. [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload).

I basically resigned on the spot, as soon as I realized it doesn't play well with Typescript, because of [this way of accessing the uploaded file](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/blob/4f81fc822d385e3e404a3266a76c103f543c3a2a/example/server.js#L26), which Typescript doesn't seem to like very much (the variable named after my `<input>` HTML element is unknown to Typescript so it does not even compile the code). There already exists [another question for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672111/), which did not receive any proper answer, but [the accepted non-answering answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62674380/1483447) suggests to move to [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), and that's what I did too.

So I ran `npm uninstall express-fileupload` followed by `npm install multer`. I tried several combinations of the multer middleware (and even without any middlewares, but calling multer directly in the /upload POST callback), but I always got the "Unexpected end of form" error. This went on until I found [this open issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144) and tried downgrading multer to 1.4.3, which did work to some extent (I started getting different errors), but in the end it wasn't an acceptable solution for me, because of the security implications of that downgrade.

Then I moved to [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy). I still got the same "Unexpected end of form" error. Googling that with "busboy" added, landed me to this [fairly recent unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74710337/error-unexpected-end-of-multipart-form-in-busboy-file-upload), where the best you can find is [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74710337/error-unexpected-end-of-multipart-form-in-busboy-file-upload#comment131882253_74710337) telling that both multer and express-fileupload use busboy behind the scenes and suggesting to use one of them instead...

So I moved back to multer, because clearly it is not multer to blame and multer seems to be what most devs out there actually use. Here below is the relevant code I've written. It's part of a minimal [Express+no-stress+Typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-express-no-stress-typescript) app I generated from scratch to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://gitlab.com/lucrus/multertest). However the generated scaffold is not minimal enough to post here the whole thing, so I put here only what I modified, the rest is just what you can get by generating a new [Express+no-stress+Typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-express-no-stress-typescript) project or by clonig [my sample repo](https://gitlab.com/lucrus/multertest).

`/server/api/controllers/examples/router.ts` file:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import express from 'express';
import controller from './controller';
export default express
  .Router()
  .post('/:dir', controller.post.bind(controller));
```

`/server/api/controllers/examples/controller.ts` file:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import multer from 'multer';

export class Controller {

  filename(_req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, cb: (error: Error|null, name: string) => void) {
    console.log("file will be named " + file.originalname);
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }

  post(req: Request, res: Response): void {
  
    console.log("Received POST request");
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: path.join('/tmp', req.params.dir), // Trusting req.params.dir is insecure, but this is only an example
      filename: this.filename
    });
    
    const upload = multer(
      { storage: storage, 
        limits: { fieldNameSize: 1000000, 
                  fieldSize: 1000000
                }
      }).single('doc');
    
    console.log("Multer is set to receive a single 'doc' upload");

    upload(req, res, (err: any) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Upload failed with error: " + err.message);
          res.status(422);
          res.json(err.message);
          res.end();
        }
      });
  }
}

export default new Controller();
```

and the `/server/common/api.yml` file, not really needed for Multer nor Express, but it enables you to test the file upload endpoint with Swagger (http://localhost:3000)

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: multertest
  description: Multer Test
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: /api/v1
tags:
- name: Examples
  description: Simple example endpoints
- name: Specification
  description: The swagger API specification
paths:
  /examples/{dir}:
    post:
      tags:
      - Examples
      description: Uploads a file
      parameters:
        - name: dir
          in: path
          description: the subdirectory where the uploaded file will be stored
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                doc:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: ok
          content: {}
  /spec:
    get:
      tags:
      - Specification
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the API specification
          content: {}
```

Finally, here is the `/server/common/server.ts` file, which I did NOT modify, but someone suggested it might be the cause of the problem. I did try setting higher upload limits and uploading files way smaller than the limits set, but nothing changed.

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import http from 'http';
import os from 'os';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import l from './logger';

import errorHandler from '../api/middlewares/error.handler';
import * as OpenApiValidator from 'express-openapi-validator';

const app = express();

export default class ExpressServer {
  private routes: (app: Application) => void;
  constructor() {
    const root = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../..');
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: process.env.REQUEST_LIMIT || '100kb' }));
    app.use(
      bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
        limit: process.env.REQUEST_LIMIT || '100kb',
      })
    );
    app.use(bodyParser.text({ limit: process.env.REQUEST_LIMIT || '100kb' }));
    app.use(cookieParser(process.env.SESSION_SECRET));
    app.use(express.static(`${root}/public`));

    const apiSpec = path.join(__dirname, 'api.yml');
    const validateResponses = !!(
      process.env.OPENAPI_ENABLE_RESPONSE_VALIDATION &&
      process.env.OPENAPI_ENABLE_RESPONSE_VALIDATION.toLowerCase() === 'true'
    );
    app.use(process.env.OPENAPI_SPEC || '/spec', express.static(apiSpec));
    app.use(
      OpenApiValidator.middleware({
        apiSpec,
        validateResponses,
        ignorePaths: /.*\/spec(\/|$)/,
      })
    );
  }

  router(routes: (app: Application) => void): ExpressServer {
    routes(app);
    app.use(errorHandler);
    return this;
  }

  listen(port: number): Application {
    const welcome = (p: number) => (): void =>
      l.info(
        `up and running in ${
          process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
        } @: ${os.hostname()} on port: ${p}}`
      );

    http.createServer(app).listen(port, welcome(port));

    return app;
  }
}
```

So the question is: how do I get a simple file upload to work with my "Express no stress typescript" application?

Comment: You can check out this post where I added a snippet to show `multer` file upload. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64844736/cheerio-doesnt-work-when-i-upload-an-html-file/64854057#64854057

Comment: @AbrarHossain thanks but unfortunately no, I can't use multer that way, because I don't know the upload folder name at coding time, but I need to calculate it based on the Request at runtime.

Comment: You should read the multer docs carefully. There is a specific example that shows you how to use `multer.diskStorage` which accepts `destination` and `filename`  which are both functions. Inside these functions, you can dynamically set the storage location and even set a desired filename. Here's the npm link for multer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: @AbrarHossain yes I know and I've already tried that, but I got the same error. It's not specified in my question because I felt it was already long enough...

Comment: "Hi", "Thanks",  jokes, statements about the OP (signature, self-steem, self-perception, feelings, background ),  statements about the world, Stack Overflow, etc. that aren't helpful to clarify the post are considered chitchat and should not be included on SO posts (questions and answers on the main site). If you need further clarification about this, please post a question on [meta].

Comment: By the way If the OP will mention the use of a tool, Google, ChatGPT or whatever, this mention should be done in such way that helps readers to better understand the question and/or reproduce the problem, not only to show how much unfruitful effort the OP did.

Comment: I've almost completely reworded my question. Some of the comments above might be outdated by now. @Rubén feel free to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code was that you were encountering a conflict between the express-openapi-validator middleware and multer while handling formdata. This conflict arose because the express-openapi-validator middleware uses multer to handle the formdata bodies, and the multer library was also being used in your code to handle the same data.

However, the good news is that the uploaded files are already available in req.body.files in your express route, as express-openapi-validator uses multer to handle the files.

To resolve the issue, you can simply use multer disk storage to handle the uploaded files. The disk storage is used to specify the destination directory and the filename for the uploaded files. The code below is a working version of the controller from your example repository:

```js
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import {
  Request,
  Response
} from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import multer from 'multer';
import stream from 'stream';

export class Controller {
  filename(
    _req: Request,
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    cb: (error: Error | null, name: string) => void
  ) {
    console.log('file will be named ' + file.originalname);
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }

  post(req: Request, res: Response): void {
    console.log('Received POST request');
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: path.join('tmp', req.params.dir), // Trusting req.params.dir is insecure, but this is only an example
      filename: this.filename,
    });

    (req.files as Array < Express.Multer.File > ).forEach(
      (file: Express.Multer.File) => {
        storage._handleFile(
          req, {
            ...file,
            stream: new stream.PassThrough(),
          },
          (err: any) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log('Upload failed with error: ' + err.message);
              res.status(422);
              res.json(err.message);
              res.end();
            }
          }
        );
      }
    );

    res.status(200);
    res.json('OK');
    res.end();
  }
}

export default new Controller();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround, e.g. disable exress-openapi-validator for the upload endpoint (named `/examples` in my question here above, but named `/upload` in my real project).

In the `server/common/server.ts` file I changed this generated line of code:

```
ignorePaths: /.*\/spec(\/|$)/,
```

into

```
ignorePaths: (path: string) => path.endsWith('/spec') || path.indexOf('/upload') >= 0,
```

This basically tells OpenApiValidator to skip validation entirely for the `/upload` endpoints. While this is not a real solution to the problem, I can actually live with it and it does answer my question: "how do I get it to work?". Hence here is to you in form of answer rather than a comment.